# Git configuration on Ubuntu [22.04 LTS]

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

I install git using

```
apt-get install git
```

this command.
After that I configure git globally using

```
git config --global user.name = "MyUserName of Github"
```

and

```
git config --global user.email = "MyEmail of Github"
```

But when I want to clone or push any git repo, it will take again my username and password. But it says authentication failed again and again.

Comment: Note that there should be no equals signs in `git config` commands: `git config --global user.name "Fred Johnson"` and `git config --global user.email fred@tycho-station.expanse`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good way to use ssh to do git related operations to your remote repo in your local system.
I will tell you the step by step process so that you will not face this issue anymore:

Step1:
Type these following commands in your command line

```
cd ~/.ssh

ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -C <you github id>

Ex:
ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -C "github@mcnz.com"
```

Step2:
Open github in your browser and go to settings and click on “ssh and gpgkeys” option and then create a new ssh key mention title and copy the output of the following command on linux terminal.

```
cat id_rsa.pub
```

And paste the output of above command in key area in github.
Click on ADD ssh key and copy the ssh url of your repository and type the command:
Ex:

```
git clone git@github.com:mcnz/lemfe
```

Everytime you want to clone using your ssh, type the below command :

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an ssh key to your GitHub account. follow this [link](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh).

Answer (score 0):

After 2021 August, github no longer support password, check link:
https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-12-git-password-authentication-is-shutting-down/

you should do what @Vikhyat say, use ssh key.

after you done, you can add below part on your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host github
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```